# Issue deleting reflexive relationship of NSManagedObject

Tags: ios, xcode, core-data, nsmanagedobject, xcdatamodel

[image]

I have an entity "Person" which has a relationship "parent".  Say I created 2 "Person" entities: "Mother" and "Child", and set the parent attribute of "Child" to "Mother".

Scenario 1:  I set the inverse of "parent" relationship.  When I view "Child" entity, I can see the "parent" attribute is set to "Mother".  But when I view "Mother" entity, I can see the "parent" attribute is set to "Child".  This is wrong and not expected.
Then I delete "Mother" and view "Child" entity again.  I can see that the "parent" attribute is still set to "Mother".  This is despite the fact that I set the delete rules to "nullify".

Scenario 2:  I set "no inverse" for "parent" relationship.  When I view "Child" entity, I can see the "parent" attribute is set to "Mother".  Then I look at "Mother" entity and nothing is set to it's "parent" attribute.  This is correct and what I expected.
However, when I delete "Mother" entity, still the "parent" attribute of "Child" entity is set to "Mother".

Scenario 3: I set the inverse of "parent" relationship to "children" which is one to many. The behavior is the same as scenario 2. Still the "parent" attribute of the "Child" entity is still set to "Mother" entity even if I already deleted the "Mother" entity and the relationship delete rule is set to "nullify".

Answer (score 0):

You have to add another attribute. `child` or `children`. And set it as inverse to `parent`.

Comment: Still the same issue as scenario 2

Comment: Did you set delete rule for both relationships?

Comment: I set it to nullify, still the parent attribute is still set to the mother entity even if i deleted the mother entity already